# Isomorphism of Localization of $A_\mathfrak{p}$ and $A_\mathfrak{q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

The question is :

> Let $\mathfrak{q} \subset \mathfrak{p}$ be two prime ideals of $A$. Show that the localization of $A_\mathfrak{p}$ at the prime ideal corresponding to $\mathfrak{q}$ is isomorphic to $A_\mathfrak{q}$.

I couldn't understand what is the question is asking for. Can someone elaborate as what it wants, and what is to be shown ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Let $S=A\smallsetminus\mathfrak p$,  $T=A\smallsetminus\mathfrak q$. As $\mathfrak q\subset \mathfrak p$, $S\subset T$.  We have a homomorphism:
\begin{align*}
A_\mathfrak p&\longrightarrow A_\mathfrak q\\
\Bigl(\frac as\Bigr)_\mathfrak p&\longmapsto \Bigl(\frac as\Bigr)_\mathfrak q
\end{align*}
by the universal property of rings of fractions (all elements of $S$ are invertible in $A_\mathfrak q$.)

On the other hand, the ideal $\mathfrak q A_\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal in $ A_\mathfrak p$, hence we can localise this ring at this prime ideal, obtaining the ring of fractions $(A_\mathfrak p)_{\mathfrak q A_\mathfrak p}$. Typically, its elements are of the form
$$\frac{\dfrac as}{\dfrac ts'}, \quad\text{where}\enspace s,s'\in S, \enspace t\in T $$
By the same universal property, you have a homomorphism from  $A_\mathfrak q$ to  $(A_\mathfrak p)_{\mathfrak q A_\mathfrak p}$.

All you have to do is to show this homomorphism is an isomorphism.

Comment: Oh ! We need $(A_\mathfrak{p})_{ \mathfrak{q}A\mathfrak{p} } \simeq A_\mathfrak{q}$

Comment: Yes, that's what you'red asked to show.